# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensor, gesture, bytebuffer

```
        TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3}, DataType.UINT8);
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4* imageSize * imageSize * 3);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.
Ideally how to define the exact buffer size? The input image size is 224*224.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I faced similar issue solved by using below code.

**Solution 1**

```
TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3}, DataType.UINT8);

            Bitmap input=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap,224,224,true);
            TensorImage image=new TensorImage(DataType.UINT8);
            image.load(input);
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer=image.getBuffer();
            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);
```

**Solution 2**

```
 ByteBuffer byteBuffer = bitmapToByteBuffer(imageBitmap, 224, 224)

 public ByteBuffer bitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap image, int width, int height) {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * width * height * 3);
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            // get 1D array of width * height pixels in image
            int[] intValues = new int[width * height];
            image.getPixels(intValues, 0, image.getWidth(), 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    
            // iterate over pixels and extract R, G, and B values. Add to bytebuffer.
            int pixel = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                    int val = intValues[pixel++]; // RGB
                    byteBuffer.putFloat(((val >> 16) & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
                    byteBuffer.putFloat(((val >> 8) & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((val & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
                }
            }
            return byteBuffer;
        }
```